# dynamicdrop down Issue in Php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dynamicdrop down, I am fetching options dynamically. Below is the code but `option "selected"` is not working in spite of giving it in first HTML tag. I want *Select Category* to be selected by default on page load.

[image: enter image description]

My PHP code:

```php
<?php  $decode = json_decode($str_json_format, TRUE); ?>
<select name="category" id="category" tabindex="6"> 
    <option value="1" selected>Select category</option>    
        <?php foreach($decode as $key => $value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: which category by default Select to be loaded on page.??

Comment: i have to pass default category id on the dropdown list.

Comment: i have attached my end issue screen shot please can you see that one sir.

Comment: <option value="1" selected>Select category</option>  is not showing in default please help.

Comment: Ok. First check value get or not in array.

Comment: values are coming for array only sir.

Answer (score 0):

Remove selected from first Option:

```
<?php  $decode = json_decode($str_json_format, TRUE);   ?>
<select name="category" id="category" tabindex="6"> 
    <option value="1">Select category</option>    
     <?php foreach($decode as $key => $value) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $value['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

Comment: Ok i'll remove selected and i'll check sir.

Comment: Hi Harsh Panchal, i checked but did not get this sir.

Comment: actually describe what you want exactly??

Comment: i have added top line in this link please click the link and see the image (enter image description here) .and not loading first option of option tag(select category)

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates the options so that the option you want is selected, which is confirmed by your image as well. Therefore you need to take a look at your client-side. You need to check whether disabling Javascript would leave you with the right option being selected. If so, then you have some Javascript code which ruins the behavior you so nicely implemented. If this is not the problem, then try to exclude your CSS rules to see whether something covers the selected option or whether the text is white and so long.